# About reverse with ollydbg

Tags: reverse-engineering, ollydbg

1. When I debug an `EXE` in it,will first stop on a specific line,how does **OD** know where to initially stop?
2. And the disassembly code is pretty short, is it true that **OD** only displays stuff within a single memory page? If true,how can I make it show all stuff?

Answer (score 1):

1. you can configure where it should stop. by default it stops on the program entry point mentioned in the PE header.
2. You can open the memory map and open any page listed there either in the dump window or in the disassembly. You can also follow any jump in the disassembly. So you can see all code.

Answer (score 0):

1. It stops at the entry point of the
   code i.e., the place where the exe
   starts execution. Theres an entry
   point defined in every EXE.
2. I don't think that is true. It shows all the code.